# Получить последний ключ в словаре Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь:

```
dicId = {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 3], 3: [7, 1, 9, 2]}
```

Нужно получить последний ключ в этом словаре.

```
dicId.keys() // возвращает набор ключей
```

Как из них выбрать последний?

Comment: В Python версии ниже 3.7 словарь является неупорядоченной коллекцией, понятие последний ключ не имеет смысла.

Comment: `list(dicId.keys())[-1]`, [но порядок ключей в Python до версии 3.6 не гарантирован...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU, или `list(dicId)[-1]`

Comment: @insolor, ну да, так короче получается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы последний элемент из произвольной коллекции получить, [можно deque() использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> import collections
>>> [last] = collections.deque(d, maxlen=1)
>>> last
'b'
```

Это O(n) по времени, O(1) в памяти алгоритм. Для сравнения: `list(d)[-1]` требует O(n) памяти.

До Питон 3.7, ключи в словаре не упорядочены, поэтому понятие "последний" смысла не имело, если не использовать что-то вроде `collections.OrderedDict` вместо `dict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)  # Python 3.6 kwargs order
>>> last = next(reversed(d))
>>> last
'b'
```

Это оптимальный O(1) по времени и памяти алгоритм. Возможно в будущем этот код будет работать и для встроенного dict: https://bugs.python.org/issue33462

Comment: Так ведь начиная с 3.6, судя по ответу в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/, а не с 3.7?

Comment: @gil9red есть гарантии языка, а есть детали реализации. Порядок гарантирован в Питоне 3.7

Comment: понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Последний ключ? Т.е. самый большой?

```
dic_id = {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6, 3], 3: [7, 1, 9, 2]}

print(max(dic_id))                # 3

print(sorted(dic_id.keys())[-1])  # 3
# Или так:
print(sorted(dic_id)[-1])         # 3
```

---

А так, вам в комментариях уже объяснили, что словарь ([до python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5909792)) являлся коллекцией с неупорядоченным набором ключей. Поэтому, или порядок в словаре не имел значения для программиста или использовался [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)